# Is there any way to access the element to which the event listener is added in the function?

Tags: javascript

I want to use element in the event listener function without declaring it elsewhere in Javascript.

```
element.addEventListener("click",function(){
//want to access element here
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

```js
element.addEventListener("click",function(e){
     console.log(this);
     console.log(e.currentTarget);
})
```

```html
<button id="element">Click</button>
```

Comment: `e.target` is not the element on which the listener is added, though - that would be `e.currentTarget`.